# Peoplepicker control for webpart custom property

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I am using a custom property in custom visula webpart. This property is used to select users from AD. for this I want to provide people picker control. Can anyone tell me how to bind this people picker control for custom webpart property.

Note: I am using visual studio 2010 and working with sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 3):

Refer the Using [People Picker control](http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/10/using-sharepoint-people-picker.html) for knowing how to bind the people picker for custom webpart property. Then for a webpart custome property pane refer to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms948930.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link... but here no custom property is used. I need to get the user data entered in text box in your suggested link then have to do some logic in my code.

Comment: I forgot to tell u. I have to add people picker to web part property pane.

Comment: Then @karthik k refer to the new link which i have given in the edited answer of mine.

Comment: karthik, does the link I had given is useful to you or not?

Comment: I need to add people picker control not the one in the link

Answer (score 2):

set the property of people editor like below:-

```
//Declaring PeopleEditor object
PeopleEditor ctrlpplPicker = new PeopleEditor ();
//Defining properties of the PeopleEditor
ctrlpplPicker.AutoPostBack = false;
ctrlpplPicker.PlaceButtonsUnderEntityEditor = true;
ctrlpplPicker.ID = "pplEditor";
ctrlpplPicker.AllowEmpty = false;
ctrlpplPicker.SelectionSet = "User, DL, SecGroup, SPGroup";
ctrlpplPicker.MultiSelect = true;
ctrlpplPicker.MaximumEntities = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display this control in your web part property pane, you need to write a custom editor part:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228018.aspx